# assign variable inside if condition in bash 4?

Tags: bash, variable-assignment

is it possible to assign variable inside if conditional in bash 4? ie. in the function below I want to assign output of executing cmd to output and check whether it is an empty string - both inside test conditional. The function should output

> "command returned: bar"

```
myfunc() {

local cmd="echo bar"
local output=

while [[ -z output=`$cmd` ]];
do
    #cmd is failing so far, wait and try again
    sleep 5
done

# great success
echo "command returned: $output"
}
```

**why the above?**

i prefer to run scripts with 'set -e' - which will cause script to terminate on first non-0 return/exit code that's not in an if/loop conditional.

with that in mind, imagine cmd is an unstable command that may exit with > 1 from time to time, and I want to keep calling it until it succeeds and i get some output.

Comment: your code is equivalent to `if [[ ! -z output=bar ]]`.

Comment: Did you try it?  Why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: the above is a trivial example - I will clarify

Comment: I just rewrote it to make it clear that that is not an assignment..

Comment: @yi_H sorry, don't follow you - i *do* want to assign value to output and check whether it is an empty string - inside test conditional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
myfunc() {

    local cmd="echo bar"
    local output=

    while ! output=$($cmd) || [[ -z output ]];
    do
        #cmd is failing so far, wait and try again
        sleep 5
    done

    # great success
    echo "command returned: $output"
}
```

Note that it is [strongly recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) to avoid the use of `set -e`.

Comment: thanks for the answer - works for me. Too bad about 'set -e' being unreliable - IMO achieving the goal behind set -e would be highly useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to do it in your conditional

As yi_H pointed out, the if is equivalent to

`if [[ ! -z output=bar ]];`

which in turn is basically

`if [[ ! -z "output=bar" ]];`

So, all you are checking is if the string "output=bar" is empty or not...

So, output=bar could actually be anything like !@#!@%=== and it would still do the same thing (that is, the expression isn't evaluated). You might have to assign the variable in a subshell somehow, but I'm not sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Since assignment won't work there, you need some workaroudn.

You could temporary do a `set +e`...

Answer (score -1):

You could use this way ...

```
$cmd
exit_status=$?

while [[ $exit_status -gt 0 ]];
do
    #cmd is failing so far, wait and try again
    sleep 5

    $cmd
    exit_status=$?
done
```

**EDIT**: This won't work with 'set -e' or other way around, don't use 'set -e' to begin with.

Comment: if 'set -e' is used (see question), and $cmd returns != 0, bash will exit after the very first line

Comment: Agreed, and that is why this answer did not include it. 'set -e' causes confusion and forces to write scripts in _not natural_ way. IMO, it is more of a trouble than it is worth. This small piece of code is the very example why it should be avoided.